# C Preprocessor include directive

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

When I include another source(I.e `stdio.h`) the preprocessor is smart enough to include only the functions that I am using in my code?

Example: Assuming this small program, would be ease to include only what I am using, and what the printf functions uses, including them recursively, but what about bigger programs?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World\n"); 
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. On the contrary:

`#include` performs textual replacement: it opens the file and copies all<sup>1</sup> of its contents into your main C file. In the process it executes all preprocessor instructions in the included file. Amongst other things, this means that it will recursively include all files that are `#include`d in the header.

`#include` does not know and does not care which part of the included file you end up using.

---

<sup>1</sup> As mentioned, preprocessor instructions *are* executed in the included file. This can modify what gets included. For example, assume the following header file `header.h`:

```c
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#ifdef NDEBUG
#  define LOG(...) ((void) 0)
#else
#  define LOG(...) log_message(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

inline void log_message(const char* filename, int line, ...) {
    // Logging code omitted for brevity.
}
#endif

// other stuff

#endif
```

Now, if your `main.c` file looks as follows:

```c
#define NDEBUG
#include "header.h"

int main(void) {
    // …
    LOG("hello");
}
```

… then, after preprocessing, your `main.c` file would looks something like this (I’m omitting some irrelevant stuff):

```
# 1 "main.c"

# 1 "./header.h" 1




# 13 "./header.h"

// other stuff


# 3 "main.c" 2

int main(void) {
    // …
    ((void) 0);
}
```

… in other words, only the part of `header.h` that corresponds to `#ifdef NDEBUG` was included, not the part in the `#else` clause. If we had included `header.h` without defining `NDEBUG`, then the included header code would have contained the definition of `log_message`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `#include` will paste verbatim *the entire file* you are targeting. However you normally include headers, which tend to look like

```c
extern int a (int b);

extern char * c (void);

static inline int d (int e, int f) {
    ...
}

extern void * g (void * h);

...
```

The code above occupies exactly zero memory (unless you start *using* one of the `inline` functions), since it is entirely composed of instructions for the compiler and nothing else.